# Travel to US from UK via Portugal – recently recovered from Covid

Tags: usa, covid-19, uk-citizens, portugal, lisbon

I am travelling from UK to Portugal with TAP on 22nd March, spending one night in Lisbon, then travelling to San Francisco on 23rd March. I recently had Covid (positive test on 23rd February) and am now recovered. I have proof of this recovery in my NHS Covid Pass app, and am triple-vaccinated.

Will the NHS app QR code be sufficient proof of recovery to enter the US?

[This CDC page says](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html)

> If you have had a positive viral test on a sample taken during the past 90 days, and you have met the criteria to travel, you may travel instead with your positive viral test results and a signed letter from a licensed healthcare provider or a public health official that states you have been cleared for travel according to CDC’s travel guidance. The positive test result and letter together are referred to as “documentation of recovery.”

I recovered less than 90 days ago, so I am ok there, but I am wondering if the app counts as a "signed letter" or if I need to get a physical piece of paper from my GP.

Comment: The US accepts antigen tests. You are probably negative by now, so this could be the easiest path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDC, at the [website you link above](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html), gives the format for the required proof of recovery if relevant:

> A letter from your healthcare provider or a public health official that clears you to travel, must have information that identifies you personally (e.g., name and date of birth) that matches the personal identifiers on your passport or other travel documents. The letter must be signed and dated on official letterhead that contains the name, address, and phone number of the healthcare provider or public health official who signed the letter.

A QR code in an app does not meet these requirements. You can either seek a letter from your healthcare provider that does meet these requirements, or get a negative rapid antigen test on the day of travel or the day before you travel to the United States (March 22nd or 23rd in your case) and show that instead.

Getting [this test at the Lisbon airport](https://www.ucs.pt/covid-19-tests-to-passengers) may be an option for you if you do not have any other way to do so. The provider at Lisbon airport charges "only" €21 for TAP passengers and €25 for other passengers for an antigen test, which is not as bad of a markup as many other airport test providers around the world.